# How to initialize class static property in angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop, angular11, aot

I write an angular library and use a static property in a class like below:

```
export class Ticket implements ITicket {
constructor(public id?: number, public title?: string) {}

// Here got error
public static get fields(): ISchemaFieldConfig[] { 
const fields: ISchemaFieldConfig[]=[{key:'title', type:'text'}];
return fields;
 }

public get fields(): ISchemaFieldConfig[] {
return Ticket.fields;
 }
}
```

When trying to build the library with --prod option, i get below error:

```
An error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Only initialized 
variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed 
by the template compiler.
```

How can i fix this issue?

How to initialize static property?

Comment: You have 2 `fields` properties, one static and one of class instance. Rename one of them, it should work.

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: I dont think you can define attr getter in static way.